# The content of website is scrolling above modal when the modal is open

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I open the modal the content of website above and below the modal button also scrolls over the modal.

I tried increasing the z-index and applying overflow property but it didn't work.

```
<a class=" read-more low-padding raised modal-trigger " data-modal="card-modal">Learn More<i class="im im-icon-Right"></i></a>

<div style="z-index: 99999999999999999999;"> 
  <div id="card-modal" class="modal modal-sm b1" style="overflow-y: hidden">
    <div class="modal-background"></div>
    <div class="modal-card modal-content">
      <header class="modal-card-head">
        <p class="modal-card-title">Tracks</p>
        <button class="delete is-medium modal-dismiss" aria-label="close"></button>
      </header>
      <section class="modal-card-body">
        <!-- User -->
        <div class="flex-card light-bordered hover-inset padding-10 mb-10">
          <div class="content content-flex">
            <div class="card-avatar">
              <img src="assets/images/ml.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-name">
              <div class="name">Machine Learning</div>
              <!--<div class="position">Software Engineer</div>-->
            </div>
            <!-- 
            <div class="card-select ml-auto">
              <i class="material-icons">done</i>
            </div>
            -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /User -->
        <!-- User -->
        <div class="flex-card light-bordered hover-inset padding-10 mb-10">
          <div class="content content-flex">
            <div class="card-avatar">
              <img src="assets/images/appdev.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-name">
              <div class="name">Mobile App Development</div>
              <!--<div class="position">Sales Representative</div>-->
            </div>
            <!--
            <div class="card-select ml-auto">
              <i class="material-icons">done</i>
            </div>
            -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /User -->
        <!-- User -->
        <div class="flex-card light-bordered hover-inset padding-10 mb-10">
          <div class="content content-flex">
            <div class="card-avatar">
              <img src="assets/images/coding.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-name">
              <div class="name">Generic Coding</div>
              <!--<div class="position">Accountant</div>-->
            </div>
            <!-- 
            <div class="card-select ml-auto">
              <i class="material-icons">done</i>
            </div>
            -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /User -->
        <!-- User -->
        <div class="flex-card light-bordered hover-inset padding-10 mb-10">
          <div class="content content-flex">
            <div class="card-avatar">
              <img src="assets/images/webdev.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-name">
              <div class="name">Web Development</div>
              <!--<div class="position">Software Engineer</div>-->
            </div>
            <!-- 
            <div class="card-select ml-auto">
              <i class="material-icons">done</i>
            </div>
            -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /User -->
        <!-- User -->
        <div class="flex-card light-bordered hover-inset padding-10 mb-10">
          <div class="content content-flex">
            <div class="card-avatar">
              <img src="assets/images/cyber.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-name">
              <div class="name">Cyber Security</div>
              <!-- <div class="position">CTO</div>-->
            </div>
            <!--
            <div class="card-select ml-auto">
               <i class="material-icons">done</i>
            </div>
            -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /User -->
      </section>
      <footer class="modal-card-foot">
        <button class="button is-link modal-dismiss">Close</button>
        <!--<button class="button btn-align raised accent-btn no-lh modal-dismiss save-btn is-disabled">Save</button> -->
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Featured image -->
<div class="column is-6 is-offset-1 has-text-centered is-hidden-mobile">
  <img class="featured-drawing" src="assets/images/illustrations/drawings/gauge.png" alt="">
</div>
```

When the modal is opened only content of modal should be displayed. No content of the webpage should be scrolling above the modal.

Comment: Your code doesn't tell us anything really.

Comment: Did you try setting a lesser `z-index` for the content that is on top of the modal?

Comment: plz if you can post a working example